# Most pythonic way to adjust input/output type for number of inputs/outputs

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I have a function that takes a string or a list of strings as an input, and returns a string or a list of strings as an output. Everyone within the function assumes it's all lists, so I have to convert both a single string input to a list, and a single string output to a string (from a list of length 1).

So right now I have this:

```
def something_stringy(input: Union[str, list]) -> Union[List[str], str]:
  if isinstance(input, str):
    input = [input]
  
  output = another_function(input)

  if len(output) > 1:
    return output[0]
  else:
    return output
```

This feels tedious and unpythonic. Is there a better way to handle this automatically?

Comment: `another_function` doesn't always return a list since you're always giving it a list?

Comment: What is unpythonic about this? Casting everything to a list to return a string at the end seems off, but I've got no clue what is in `another_function()` however at first glance it seems it would be better to perform the altering of data inside of `another_function` so you don't possibly duplicate areas of logic or put logic in multiple places where it's easiest to alter in 1...I normally turn anything that is duplicated more than once in my code to a method/function, it keeps things more simple

Comment: This sort of signature `def something_stringy(input: Union[str, list]) -> Union[List[str], str]:` is an anti-pattern. Accepting a union of types is slightly less problematic, although can still be tedious, but try to return a non-union type

Comment: "This feels tedious and unpythonic. Is there a better way to handle this automatically?" No, there is no way to handle this automatically. This is a fundamental issue with the *design*.

Comment: I'd lean towards, if possible, just always accepting and returning a list, i.e. `def something_stringy(input: list) -> list[str]:`. That removes a lot of logic from your code, simplifies the function signature, and the only thing the caller has to do is optionally wrap their parameter in a list.

Comment: thanks everyone -- 1) just for context, the actual function was to find a dictionary in a list of dictionaries where a provided Key = provided Value, then return a variable number of values from that dictionary ... 2) thanks for the typing notes, I'm still learning best practices on that!